# How to use ini file in Jenkins for .NET application?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Previously we used Finalbuilder application. In that we can able to use the variable values from the ini file in finalbuilder application.

```
user=sample
passwrod=1234#
path=D:\Testing\Sampletest\newproject
```

For example, In above ini file, user name, password, and project path are defined. i can use the same variable in finalbuilder project by loading the ini file.

Similarly, can i use the variables and its value assigned in ini file in Jenkins application? If so, what plugin do i need to use and how to use?

Comment: It's `password`, not `passwrod`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EnvInjenct plugin is what you are looking for. Check for details and usage from

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin

Comment: Yes. This is what am looking for.